# Restart Service for App on SD Card When SD Card Is Remounted

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

Due to overwhelming user complaints I have decided try allowing users of my Android application to move it to the SD card as per [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html).  However, a core feature of my application requires a background service to be continuously running.  When someone who has moved my app to their SD card mounts their SD card for whatever reason, my background service will be killed.

That's all okay by me, as long as I can restart the service at the first available opportunity.  Unfortunately, despite the [install-location](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html) guide claiming I can use the Broadcast Intent [`ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE) to detect when the SD card is remounted locally, the documentation for that flag itself, [this newsgroup discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9ed73e072e0ea22a?hl=en), and my own testing show that this broadcast is not delivered to the applications which become available. Only applications which have not been moved to the SD card get the Broadcast Intent.

Is there any way to restart my background service without waiting for the user to open my app after the SD card is remounted?

Comment: Hey Alex, I am facing the same problem. How did you manage to restart your service in background ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not reliably. You could hook into permission-less broadcast `Intents` (e.g., `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`) that should fire eventually and get control that way. As Ms. Hackborn indicates, the right answer is for `ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE` to be fixed. You might also see if some SD card-related broadcast happens to occur after external applications are available (e.g., `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED`), though I would expect all of those to have passed before the external application is available.